# How to show only required model schema in Swagger-UI

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui

I have a `rest` based web-application that uses a schema document to show the output data fetched from db. When i use swagger-ui for documentation, it shows the full schema.

See the picture below,

[image]

Is there a way i can, make swagger show only the schema i want and not rest of it?

For example, here in the ping method, i want to show only the timeZone,MsgStatus, response code etc. But currently it is showing the full schema.

**PingController.java**

```
@Api(basePath = "v1/system/ping", value = "ping", description = "***Insert Description Here***", produces = "application/json")
@RestController
public class PingController {

@Autowired
private UsersJSON usersJSON;

@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Ping The Server", notes = "Pings the Server")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Invalid Request URL")
})

@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/system/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public Users getPing() {
    return ping();
}

private Users ping() {
    Users users = null;
    try {
        users = usersJSON.buildDefaultUsersTemplate();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex) {
        LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
    } 
    return users;
 }

}
```